# Evernote python django- how to get listNotebooks() ?

Tags: evernote, evernote-app-notebook

I followed the instructions and got the access token. Yet when I use their sample code to call `listNotebooks()` I get 3 things -- "notes", "documents" and "web clippings" in a list. There are no names of actual notebooks. There is also no error. How to get the list of notebooks.

Comment: What do you mean by no names of actual notebooks? Do you have notebooks named `notes`, `documents` or `web clippings`? Any code snippet?

Comment: The code is mostly from the django python sample. I have received the access token following their instructions and it is also in the format it should be acc to [their website](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php), i.e.- "S=..:U=....."

Comment: The callback code in oauth/views.py that i edited is `def callback(request):
    accessToken  = "S=s1:...."

    client = EvernoteClient(token=accessToken)
    note_store = client.get_note_store()
    notebooks = note_store.listNotebooks()
    for n in notebooks:
        print "\n", n, "\n"

    client = EvernoteClient(token=accessToken)
    user_store = client.get_user_store()
    print user_store.getUser()

    return render_to_response('oauth/callback.html', {'notebooks': notebooks})` I go to server-address:port/callback and get the output

Comment: I have no notebooks notes or anything called notes documents and web clipping. I have several notebooks each having several notes. None of those are printed or displayed in the browser or terminal.

Comment: The user store does display my name though. Its very weird if this is not how its supposed to be. Any hints why this is happening???

Comment: Your API calls go to sandbox.evernote.com, right? Did you make sure you don't have those notebooks there?

Comment: Thanks, it works now! That was the problem!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was everytime I called `EvernoteClient(token=accessToken,sandbox = False)`
I had to pass sandbox= False. Not passing meant it was true by default. And the three notebooks:  web clippings, etc are in sandbox.evernote.com by default.

Thanks to [kentaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1691992/kentaro)